# Unhandled Runtime Error AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, backend

I am working on a project which takes a video file from user and uploads it on my created S3 bucket. For that thing I am using axios but after selecting the file it throws me error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
>
> Call Stack
> settle
> node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js (19:0)
> XMLHttpRequest.onloadend
> node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js (111:12)

I checked and rechecked my env file and name of the access key it has but still not resolved.

```
api route.js file code:

import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

export async function POST(req){
    const formData =  await req.formData();
    const file = formData.get('file');
    
    const {name,type}=file;
    const data=await file.arrayBuffer();
    const s3client = new S3Client({
        region:'eu-north-1',
        credentials:{
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        },

    });

    const id=uniqid();
    const ext= name.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
    const newName= id + '.'+ ext;

    const uploadCommand= new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket:process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
        Body:data,
        ACL:'public-read',
        ContentType:type,
        Key:newName,
    }) ;

    await s3client.send(uploadCommand);
    return Response.json({name,ext,newName,id})
}



upload form.js file code:

'use client'
import UploadIcon from "./UploadIcon";
import axios from "axios";

export default function UploadForm(){
    async function upload(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        
        const files =ev.target.files;
        if(files.length>0){
            const file = files[0];
            const res = await axios.postForm('/api/upload',{
                file,
            });
            console.log(res.data);
        }
    }


    return (
        <label className="bg-green-600 py-2 px-4 rounded-full inline-flex gap-2 border-2 border-purple-700/50 cursor-pointer">
        <UploadIcon/>
<span>Choose file</span>
<input onChange={upload} type="file" className="hidden"/>
</label>
    );
}
```

Here uploadform file is in components folder and route.js has separate directory api->upload->route.js